# Laravel - where to store common model functions & how to access them from controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model, extends

I have a number of functions that are used by *most* of my models
so it makes sense to store them centrally rather than repeating code.

For example, I have a function that finds a random row from whichever table I need:

```
function getRandomRow() {
    $rowCount = DB::connection('mydatabasename')
                ->table('my_table_name')
                ->selectRaw("FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset")
                ->first();

    $offset = $rowCount->offset;

    $randomRow = DB::connection('mydatabasename')
                    ->table('my_table_name')
                    ->select()
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->first();

    return $randomRow;
}
```

I've looked at [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26704488/3092596) (extends) and [traits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31463474/3092596) - as well as the [docs on polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) - but it's not clear which is the most efficient and how to access the table name (associated with the model being used) within the common function.

My questions:
- where do I put this function so that it can be used by all models ?
- how do I write the code so that the `'my_table_name'` uses the correct model table ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I posted my solution below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution I found is to create a parent model / class - as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320421/3092596) to a different question - for the current example let's call it `BaseModel`.

For Laravel this is stored along with the other models, directly in the `App` directory

...in my case the parent model / class can be `abstract` as it doesn't need to have it's own table (also meaning the `BaseModel` functions can only be accessed via a child model):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    // ...put common model functions here
}
```

The trick to get this working (where a `BaseModel` function will need to access a child model's table) is to:
- have each child model / class `extend` the `BaseModel` class
- ensure that the `$table` is defined in all the child models - as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580458/3092596):

```
class MyFunkyModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'funktown';

    // ...put child specific functions here

}
```

which means `$this->table` can be used in the `BaseModel` abstract parent class to reference the designated `$table` of the child model / class:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    function getRandomRow() {
        $rowCount = DB::connection('mydatabasename')
                        ->table($this->table)
                        ->selectRaw("FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset")
                        ->first();

        $offset = $rowCount->offset;

        $profileRow = DB::connection('mydatabasename')
                        ->table($this->table)
                        ->select()
                        ->offset($offset)
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->first();

        return $profileRow;
    }
}
```

Now from a controller you can access any functions stored in the `BaseModel` simply via the child model(s):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\MyFunkyModel;
use App\MySeriousModel;
use App\MyHappyModel;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function getRandomName($type){
        switch ($type) {
            case 'funky':
                $modelFunky = new MyFunkyModel;
                $funkyRow = $modelFunky->getRandomRow();
                $randomName = $funkyRow->funky_name_column;
                break;
            case 'serious':
                $modelSerious = new MySeriousModel;
                $seriousRow = $modelSerious->getRandomRow();
                $randomName = $seriousRow->serious_name_column;
                break;
            case 'happy':
                $modelHappy = new MyHappyModel;
                $happyRow = $modelHappy->getRandomRow();
                $randomName = $happyRow->happy_name_column;
                break;
        return $randomName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use both `inheritance` and `trait` for this. But highly recommend to use `Eloquent` models rather than `DB::table()`. The reason is if somehow the table name get changed you have to change it everywhere. With `Eloquent` you only need to mention table name once in you model.

```
protected $table = 'new_table_name'
```

**using inheritance**

structure you `BaseModel` and `class` as follows.

```
class BaseModel extends Model {
    public static function getRandomRow()
    {
        $rowCount = self::selectRaw("FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset")
            ->first();

        $offset = $rowCount->offset;

        $randomRow = self::select()
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit(1)
            ->first();

        return $randomRow;
    }
}

class YourModel extends BaseModel {
    // getRandomRow() available here
}
```

**using trait**

structure your `trait` and `class` as follows.

```
trait BaseTrait {
    public static function getRandomRow()
    {
        $rowCount = self::selectRaw("FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset")
            ->first();

        $offset = $rowCount->offset;

        $randomRow = self::select()
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit(1)
            ->first();

        return $randomRow;
    }
}

class YourClass {
    use BaseTrait;
    // getRandomRow() available here
}
```

Either way you can access your method like

```
class yourController {
    public function youMethod()
    {
        $rows = YourModel::getRandomRow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any reason to use static functions - while obviously necessary with Traits and Helpers - with an inheritance type BaseModel ?  While it's technically possible, it creates code that is inconsistent in some ways - half your functions in a model will by called by `MyModel->modelFunction()` and half by `MyModel::modelFunction()` - which is another speedhump in coding (remembering which functions are in `MyModel`, and which are in `BaseModel`).

Comment: also thanks for the advice on Eloquent vs Query Builder - we've found Eloquent far too restrictive for complex queries - so we only use Query Builder. In addition you can use `$this->table` in QB to avoid repeating the table name - which makes it the same as Eloquent for that purpose.  Our tables names change very infrequently and most IDEs have fairly competent find/replace features these days - so I'm not sure that's a deal breaker.